# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types Error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting an error as object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types when i add pic1 in this code. The pic1 is from img table in database.

```cs
public List<RentModel>GetData()
{
    List<RentModel> dataList = new List<RentModel>();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM rent FULL OUTER JOIN img ON rent.id= img.r_id",con);
     
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    
    DataTable dtdata= new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    sqlda.Fill(dtdata);
    
    con.Close();
    foreach(DataRow dr in dtdata.Rows)
    {
        dataList.Add(new RentModel
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]),
            tittle = dr["tittle"].ToString(),
            descrip = dr["descrip"].ToString(),
            area = Convert.ToInt32(dr["area"]),
            areaUnit = dr["areaUnit"].ToString(),
            bathroom = dr["bathroom"].ToString(),
            bedroom = dr["bedroom"].ToString(),
            province= dr["province"].ToString(),
            city= dr["city"].ToString(),
            stadress = dr["stadress"].ToString(),
            furnished = dr["furnished"].ToString(),
            p_type = dr["p_type"].ToString(),
            price = dr["price"].ToString(),
            pic1 = dr["pic1"].ToString(),
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `as` keyword to try casting to the expected type. Since `DBNull` is its own type the casting will fail and `null` will be returned. E.g.

```cs
descrip = dr["descrip"] as string,
```

But of course you must use the right type. E.g. if the image is stored as bytes (e.g. in a VARBINARY column), `pic1` must be of type `byte[]` and you must write:

```cs
pic1 = dr["pic1"] as byte[],
```

If columns of some value type are nullable, make the field nullable as well. E.g., `int? area`

```cs
 area = dr["area"] as int?,
```

or use `int area` and write

```cs
 area = (dr["area"] as int?) ?? 0,
```

If a column is declared as NOT NULL in SQL then simply cast:

```cs
area = (int)dr["area"],
```

Note that the static return type of `dr["xy"]` is `object`, but the values already have the right type (the type corresponding to the column type) and you must only cast to get the typed value. You must actually not convert the value, unless the field or property type is different from the column type.

Comment: Appreciated your answer kindly also tell me that when i run this code i get two tabs of information in which one is tittle ,decrip ,area etc and then other one is picture i want to make it in only one tab pic data is in another table it mean it run one more time for just picture tell me the solution

Comment: I do not quite understand. Your query already joins the two tables and puts them into one single DataTable (it should probably rather use a LEFT OUTER JOIN, so).

Answer (score 0):

You can try comparing the pic1 column to DBNull:

```cs
dataList.Add(new RentModel
{
    ....,
    pic1 = (dr["pic1"] == DBNull.Value)? string.Empty : dr["pic1"].ToString()
});
```

Comment: still facing the same error